# owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this , is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[on web] tried to fit some widgets inside a `FittedBox` like this :

```
 FittedBox(
   fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
   child: AnimatedContainer(...)
 )
```

but screen and console show only this message :

[image: error]

there's nothing else in the console

what's the next step here ? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More Info was provided by the framework after a little messing around with the code , like extra children , random sizes to parents . . .

Error >> `... object was given an infinite size during layout`

ultimately some like this worked :

```
FittedBox(
 fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
 child: Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .65,
   child: AnimatedContainer(...)
)
```

Answer (score 23):

I was getting this error inside of a CustomScrollView because one of my widgets wasn't inside of a SliverToBoxAdapter.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text('Activity',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18),),
    ],
  ),
)
```

I'd just make sure all widgets in your sliver list are actually slivers.

Comment: This answer is correct. It solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because somewhere in my code, I applied a wrong widget mistakenly, and that was the same stateless widget that I was writing. To make it more clear:

```
stateless widget - MyWidget //For example
.
.
.
Now somewhere in between the code:

Column(
children: [
MyWidget(), //This went wrong, I was supposed to Use some other widget.
]);
```

Comment: Same happened with me. I was calling HomePage() within HomePage() widget. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as a result of incorporating multiple Consumer widgets of the same  model Provider.
Solution was to follow Provider package guidelines of incorporating one Consumer widget at the top of the widget tree where the state object is to be shared from.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering this because none of the Answers above worked for me:

My IDE (VSCode) changed the initState() method to async because I accidentally wrote a method as "await" and then just tapped the autoerrorfix

Answer (score 0):

I just wrap with container (with height=constant)
it worked for me

Comment: same as the accepted answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

if the error appears when you have clicked button at the bottom sheet, just set enabledrag to false.

```
      builder: (context) => BottomSheet(
                  onClosing: () {},
                  enableDrag: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of my bloc provider

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocProvider(
```

your build method should return BlocProvider first !